# Multiple instances of a class with different content

Tags: python, multiple-instances

I'm trying to make a list of objects with different content but when I create the instance, it edits all other instances.

```
class Example(object):
    name = ''

   @classmethod
   def __init__(cls, name):
       cls.name = name

col = []
col.append(Example('text1'))
col.append(Example('text2'))
for item in col:
    print item.name
```

And it prints

```
'text2'
'text2'
```

When I expect it to print

```
'text1'
'text2'
```

I've also tried with

```
var = Example('text1')
col.append(var)
```

And I can't set different variable names because I want it to create instances in a loop.

Comment: Why did you make `__init__` a class method then? Don't do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't make `__init__` a class method; it a *instance initializer*:

```
class Example(object):
    name = ''

   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
```

By making it a class method, you made it alter the class, not the new instance created.

Without the `@classmethod` decorator, the class-level `name` attribute is entirely optional, you can remove it for most uses.

Comment: That make it, thank you. And thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
class Example(object):
   def __init__(self, name):
       self.name = name
```